# How can we find the elementary divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> We consider the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{R}[t]$ and the $R$-module $M=\mathbb{R}^3$, where $a\cdot x$ ($a\in R,x\in M$) is defined as usual if $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and $a\cdot x=(x_1, 0, 0)$ if $a=t, x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

From the structure theorem for finitely generated $R$-module there is a list $p_1, p_2, \dots , p_n$ irreducible of $R$ and a list $k_1, k_2, \dots , k_n$ positive integers such that $$M\cong R/\langle p_1^{k_1}\rangle \oplus \dots \oplus R/\langle p_n^{k_n}\rangle$$

How can we find these lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_n$ must each annihilate a nontrivial submodule of $M$, so to identify these polynomials, try seeing if you can find elements of $\mathbb R[t]$ that annihilate some non-zero element of $M$.

Comment: Which form have the elements of $M$ ?

Comment: The elements of $M$ are just triples of real numbers. So, for example if we tried checking the action of the irreducible polynomial $p=2+t$ on $m=(1,2,3)$, we would get $p \cdot m = (2+t) \cdot (1,2,3) = 2 \cdot (1,2,3) + t\cdot(1,2,3) = (2,4,6)+(1,0,0) = (3,4,6)$. If the result had come out to $(0,0,0)$, then we would have identified $p$ one of the $p_i$ and $m$ as an element of one of the summands in the decomposition of the structure theorem. So try different values for $p$ and $m$ and see if you can find one that works.

Comment: When we have that $p=\sum_{i=0}^n a_it^i, m=(m_1, m_2, m_3)$ then $$p\cdot m=a_0\cdot (m_1, m_2, m_3)+\sum_{i=1}^n t^i (m_1, m_2, m_3) \\ =(a_0m_1, a_0m_2, a_0m_3)+n(m_1, 0, 0)=(a_0m_1+nm_1, a_0m_2, a_0m_3)\\ =((a_0+n)m_1, a_0m_2, a_0m_3)$$ 

We get $p\cdot m=(0,0,0)$, in the following cases: 

 $$1) \ \ a_0=0 \land n=0$$ 
 $$2) \ \ a_0=0 \land m_1=0$$ 
 $$3) \ \ m_2=0 \land m_3=0 \land n=-a_0 (\text{ when } a_0<0 )$$  
 $$4) \ \ m_2=0 \land m_3=0 \land m_1=0$$  

or not?

Comment: It looks like you dropped the coefficient $a_i$ of $t^i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Oh yes... It should be as follows: $$p\cdot m=a_0\cdot (m_1, m_2, m_3)+\sum_{i=1}^n a_it^i (m_1, m_2, m_3) \\ =(a_0m_1, a_0m_2, a_0m_3)+\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i m_1, 0, 0)=(a_0m_1+m_1\sum_{i=1}^na_i, a_0m_2, a_0m_3)\\ =((a_0+\sum_{i=1}^na_i)m_1, a_0m_2, a_0m_3)$$ or not?

Comment: Is this correct so far?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.

Comment: Therefore, we have the following: $$ 1) \ \ a_i=0 , i=0, \dots , n$$ 
$$2) \ \ a_0=0 \land  a_i\neq 0 (i=1, \dots , n) \land m_1=0$$ 
$$3) \ \ m_2=0 \land m_3=0 \land a_0+\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0  $$ 
$$4) \ \ m_2=0 \land m_3=0 \land m_1=0$$ or not?

Comment: More or less right. Now can you find specific choices of the $m_i$ and $p_i$ that work and are non-trivial, i.e., as in your cases (2) and (3)?

Comment: For $p=t+2t^2$ and $m=(0,1,2)$, we get $p\cdot m=(0,0,0)$, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40442/discussion-between-brent-kerby-and-mary-star).